# React - changing diplayed component without realoading

Tags: reactjs

I'm making blog app using django and react. Currently I'm working on reaction system. I managed to make it, but I'd like to replace `<Like/>` component with `<Dislike/>` without reloading page.
It look like that

like component

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {useState} from 'react'

export default function Like({userID, postID, liked}){
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    const [Liked, setLiked] = useState(liked)
    
    formData.append('user', userID);
    formData.append('post', postID);
    formData.append('active', 'true');
    
    const like = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }
        
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/leave-like/', requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            if(response.ok){
                return response.json();
            }
        })
        
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
    
    return(
        <div onClick={like} id={`post${postID}`}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon className="fa-lg" icon={faHeart} id={`post${postID}`}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

dislike

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default function DisLike({userID, postID}){
    
    // here will be dislike function working similar to like but it will be making request removing reaction object from dbbut it's not been already made
    
    return(
        <div id={`post${postID}`}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon className="fa-lg" icon={faHeart} id={`post${postID}`} style={{color: "#ff0000",}} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

post

`````
export default function Post(props){
    
    
    const [userID, setUserID] = useState(props.uID);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState(localStorage.username);
    
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false)// check if logged user already left reaction
    const [likes, setLikes] = useState(props.likes)

    useEffect(() => {
        for(let i = 0; i<props.likedBy.length; i++){
            //console.log(props.likedBy[i])
            if(props.likedBy[i] == username){
                //console.log("liked")
                setLiked(true)
            }
        }
    }, [])

    return(
        <div className="card" style={divStyle} key={props.id}>
            
             ``` some post content````
            
            <p>{likes}</p>
            
            {liked ? <DisLike/> : <Like userID={userID} postID={props.id} liked={liked}/>}
                
                
            </div>
            <div className="card-footer">
              <small className="text-muted">Last updated {props.posted} ago</small>
                <div>
                    <small>posted by {props.email}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    )
}
`````

its all about this

```
{liked ? <DisLike/> : <Like userID={userID} postID={props.id} liked={liked}/>}
```

is it even possible to render another component after submiting form using first one ?

edit:
If I render both components at the same time but one of them has display:none style would it be possible to achive what i'm trying to achieve?